# Python mmap.write() writes not only in the memory, but also on the disk

Tags: python, windows, memory-mapped-files

I'm on the Windows, using mmap module for sharing information between two Python scripts. My problem is to write data into a memory for being accessed from other script, without writing it on a disk. According to [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/mmap.html?highlight=mmap), `mmap.write()` method is exactly what I'm looking for: **Write the bytes in bytes into memory at the current position of the file pointer and return the number of bytes written**.

I'm running the following code to test writing into memory and face 2 problems:

```
def test_write_mmf(json_path):

    # Know the file size to read from the memory
    file_size = os.path.getsize(json_path)

    # Open and read file amd MMF
    json_file = open(json_path, "r+", encoding="utf8")
    mapped_file = mmap.mmap(json_file.fileno(), 0)
    mapped_file.seek(0)
    buffer_for_json = mapped_file[:file_size]

    # Content is JSON, so load it
    json_data = json.loads(buffer_for_json.decode("utf-8"))

    # do some in-memory edits
    json_data[0]["response_index"] = 0
    json_data[0]["description"] = "INSTALL"

    # write it back into memory
    json_string = json.dumps(json_data)
    json_bytes = bytearray(json_string, encoding="utf8")
    mapped_file.seek(0)

    # It supposed to write into memory only!
    mapped_file.write(bytes(json_bytes))

    # Here I wait to check if the file was written
    m.getch()

    # Supposed to be real flush content to disk
    mapped_file.flush()
```

1. At the line `mapped_file.write(bytes(json_bytes))` I'm expecting my changes are still in the memory, but it is in a file on the disk already.
2. This problem is not connected to previous, but I realized when the written content smaller than it was before, I see the "tail" of the previous data still remains in the rewritten file. Is there a way to erase opened file? I tried `json_file.truncate()` with Permission Denied `(WinError=13)` error.

Comment: The OS load balances the working set of every process using a least-recently used algorithm. A modified ('dirty') page can be, and likely will be, swapped to disk (mapped file or paging file) without an explicit `flush` (e.g. WinAPI `FlushViewOfFile`).

Comment: In Windows, you can't resize a file while it's mapped, but mmap has a `resize` method that takes care of the details for you, i.e. `UnmapViewOfFile`; `CloseHandle` on the file mapping; `SetFilePointer`, `SetEndOfFile` on the File handle; and then remap it via `CreateFileMapping` and `MapViewOfFile`.

Comment: Change `mapped_file = mmap.mmap(json_file.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)` to prevent writing through to file on disk in Windows platform.

Comment: We normally use structred data when writing into mmap region. With structured data, we know the lenght of each data field, avoiding the 2) situation you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You need Copy-on-write type memory mapping for that, not write-through.

```py
mapped_file = mmap.mmap(json_file.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_COPY)
```

From the Python's [mmap](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/mmap.html#mmap.ACCESS_COPY) module doc:

> For both the Unix and Windows versions of the constructor, access may
> be specified as an optional keyword parameter. access accepts one of
> four values: ACCESS_READ, ACCESS_WRITE, or ACCESS_COPY to specify
> read-only, write-through or copy-on-write memory respectively, or
> ACCESS_DEFAULT to defer to prot. access can be used on both Unix and
> Windows. If access is not specified, Windows mmap returns a
> write-through mapping. The initial memory values for all three access
> types are taken from the specified file. Assignment to an ACCESS_READ
> memory map raises a TypeError exception. Assignment to an ACCESS_WRITE
> memory map affects both memory and the underlying file. Assignment to
> an **ACCESS_COPY memory map affects memory but does not update the
> underlying file**.